# Name attribute inside span element

Tags: php, html

It is possible to use name attribute inside span element, and to fetch values using name as same like other input elements in php.

```
<span name = "first"></span>

<?php 
$username = $_POST['first'];
?>
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. How are you trying to fetch the value from that attribute? Are you using jQuery/JavaScript?

Comment: Via a normal form POST, no, if you are using jQuery and AJAX'ing then possibly.

Answer (score 2):

```
<span name = "first"></span> //invalid
```

this is not possible. you can have name attribute on only input tags(which user can able to give some input).

if you mention name attribute to span how you can give value.. think in that perspective

```
<?php 
$username = $_POST['first'];//nothing you will get here
?>
```